# ViewData as a hyperlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hyperlink, view, viewdata

I an ASP.NET MVC we can pass some data via a `ViewData` and then show it on a page:

```
<%: ViewData["Foo"]%>
```

**But how to make a hyperlink out of it?**

Something like following:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink(ViewData["Foo"], "Index", "Home") %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast it to `string`:

```
Html.ActionLink((string)ViewData["Foo"], "Index", "Home")
```

In general, however, try to avoid using `ViewData` and use a strongly typed `ViewModel` instead. (Thus, you would have avoided the problem in this question, btw).

Comment: Thanks, it works! I'll pay attention to your remark about ViewData vs ViewModel. +1